# Type Problem: How can useState(react-hook) be used as a global variable when contextAPI is used in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, use-state, react-context

--Development environment: window10, VScode
--Tech: react --typescript

I only want to use contextAPI to manage the variables globally.(I don't use useReducer)
Variables are objects received from axios.

```
    const result = await axios.post('/register', {name,username,password})
        
    console.log(result.data);
```

I want to manage variables from the top component using useState.
But I can't do what I want because of the type problem.

```
// AuthContext.tsx
import {createContext, useContext} from 'react';

export type AuthType = {
    auth: object;
    setAuth: (a: object) => void;
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthType>({
    auth: {a:1},
    setAuth: () => console.log('why not worked??')
})

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext);
```

I declared type of auth as an object to receive result.data(this variable is object).
In order to globally manage variables with useState hook, we wrote the following in the top-level component.

```
// App.tsx
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components';
import ToolBar from './components/ToolBar';
import MainPage from "./pages/MainPage";
import LoginPage from "./pages/LoginPage";
import RegisterPage from "./pages/RegisterPage";
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthContext, AuthType } from './contexts/AuthContext';

const Container = styled.div`
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
`;

function App() {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState<AuthType>()
    return (
        <Container>
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{auth,setAuth}} >
                <ToolBar/>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' component={MainPage} exact />
                    <Route path='/auth/register' component={RegisterPage} exact/>
                    <Route path='/auth/login' component={LoginPage} exact/>
                </Switch>
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        </Container>
    )
}
export default App
```

However, type error occurred at the value of property of the tag AuthContext.Provider
The contents are as follows.
**the error of auth**

> Type 'AuthType | undefined' is not assignable to type 'object'.
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'object'.ts(2322)

**the error of setAuth**

> Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<AuthType | undefined>>' is not assignable to type '(a: object) => void'.
> Types of parameters 'value' and 'a' are incompatible.
> Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<AuthType | undefined>'.
> Type 'object' is not assignable to type '(prevState: AuthType | undefined) => AuthType | undefined'.
> Type '{}' provides no match for the signature '(prevState: AuthType | undefined): AuthType | undefined'.ts(2322)

I couldn't find any information and knowledge related to this. So I'd like to ask the seniors.
I'm sorry for the low level of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have undefined initial state. Additionally you are declaring the state type to be the *entire* context type when in actuality you are only storing the "auth" type, an object.

```
const [auth, setAuth] = useState<AuthType>(); // <-- undefined
```

Since you defined the `auth` state to be an object, provide an object as valid initial state and declare the type.

```
const [auth, setAuth] = useState<object>({}); // <-- empty object
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I understand your explanation. However, the error in auth was resolved, but the error in setAuth was not resolved. Can you have an additional answer about this?

Comment: @tojaeung I see, I missed that you had issues with both the state ***and*** state updater function types, sorry. I see that you've likely mis-typed your state, please see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Senior!! Global management of variables using useState is difficult, so I try to find another way. However, senior`s answer inspired me.

Answer (score 0):

You declared `<AuthType>` for typescript and it is good but your hook is empty now!

if you wanna your hook to be an object so:

```
useState({})
```